# Adding header using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have to set a header Key:XXXXXXX which I have inserted twice still the header doesn't gets inserted.

I am getting data from an API so I need to add headers for the same but apparently something is wrong in my code that when I checked it using Live Headers Addon chrome the headers don't show.

But if I do it manually(Inserting Headers) using a chrome extension it gets inserted.

**Code**

```js
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {

        // Check if the XMLHttpRequest object has a "withCredentials" property.
        // "withCredentials" only exists on XMLHTTPRequest2 objects.
        {

            xhr.open(method, url, true)
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Key", "ac6e6ff85e0774");
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Secret", "9261fabe594");


        }
    } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {

        // Otherwise, check if XDomainRequest.
        // XDomainRequest only exists in IE, and is IE's way of making CORS requests.
        xhr = new XDomainRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Key", "47385e0774");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Secret", "b034e594");

    } else {

        // Otherwise, CORS is not supported by the browser.
        xhr = null;

    }
    return xhr;
}

function makeCorsRequest() {
    // This is a sample server that supports CORS.
    var url = 'https://www.cryptocurrencychart.com/api/coin/list';
    var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET',url);
    console.log(xhr);
    if (!xhr) {
        console.log('CORS not supported');
        return ('GODDAMNIT');
    }

    // Response handlers.
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Key", "c2b64fc6e64");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Secret", "cb0asdw64");
    xhr.onload = function() {

        var text = xhr.responseText;
        console.log('going in');



        console.log(text);

    };
    xhr.onerror = function() {
        console.log('Woops, there was an error making the request.');
    };

    xhr.send();
}
makeCorsRequest();
```

What am i doing wrong here?

**EDIT**
This gets printed in console

Woops, there was an error making the request

OPTIONS https://www.cryptocurrencychart.com/api/coin/list 500 ()
makeCorsRequest

Failed to load https://www.cryptocurrencychart.com/api/coin/list: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 500

**EDIT2**

These are my requests and responses

```
OPTIONS /api/coin/list HTTP/1.1
Host: www.cryptocurrencychart.com:443
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,es;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers: access-control-allow-origin,key,secret
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://evil.com/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36
X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id: (28BB0A368XXXXDD3C9EE95A829XXXBF)

HTTP/1.1 500
cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
content-type: application/json
date: Sat, 03 Mar 2018 17:08:56 GMT
expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
pragma: no-cache
server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
set-cookie: PHPSESSID=brexxxxx6c4ptr5bs8ns7dlf11; path=/
status: 500
```

**PLEASE NOTE THAT** THE HEADERS INSTEAD OF GOING IN THE REQUESTS are going in the `Access-Control-Request-Headers: access-control-allow-origin,key,secret`

Comment: First you cannot set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` from the client. It would be useless if the client could tell the server what origins to allow.  Second the request you looked at was probably the pre-flight request that gets sent out when using custom headers. And since the server you are trying to use does not handle those it responds back with a 500 error, hence your full request fails.

Comment: Also that api looks like it is meant to be used  Server side, not client side, as anything where you have a key and a secret value probably isnt meant to be publicly seen

Comment: What's the return value of createCORSRequest?

Comment: Nothing just call that function and execute it .

Comment: Also  THe key and secret are fake so no fear @sahim erbay

Comment: But if I intercept the request and add headers Key and Secret using burp Suite etc it works like a charm @ Patrick Evans

Comment: @shutup1 well if you put this for the world to see all they would have to do is go into dev tools, look at your JS code and now they have your key/secret to the api you're using. Which is why most API calls like this belong on the server.

Comment: @shutup1 and im sure burp suite executes their code server side as well, store the key and secret on server, and just have your JS call that instead of doing it in JS. This would 100% solve your problem. If you have 0 server side experience, I would youtube some basic PHP how to create a simple api videos, and your result will be much better. No more worrying about CORS.

Comment: @ jdmdevdotnet thanx for comment but I have make a simple rest api in python using django,but what do u mean by this line "and just have your JS call that instead of doing it in JS"

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet thanx man but the KEY and SECRET are FAKE :P

Comment: And I am using Modify Headers to add headers(Key and Secret )  to the requests

Comment: Well then whats the point of them? That makes no sense. Are you saying they're fake on here? That's fine, but I imagine you're supplying them because the API requires it, right? So in your actual code you'll need to expose the real key and secret. Otherwise, what's the point of supplying them in the first place?

Comment: @shutup1 Well I mean have your JS call your server side code (PHP, Python..etc) via ajax call. Have the key and secret live on the server side code, so in your python or PHP code. Call the API you're trying to currently call in JS, in your server side code instead of calling the API in your JS which is exposed for everyone to see. And you can set rules for your API to only accept requests coming from your IP, or the IP of where your application lives. That way, nobody else can access it, and they cant see the keys either bc it's not sent to client.

Comment: @shutup1 if that is the chrome extension you are talking about in the question that is why, chrome extensions dont suffer from cors as they arent making a request from any particular domain. They can also manipulate requests as well to make them bypass cors by manipulating the response to include the right cors header